# jQuery - Add class if input text is equal to answer

Tags: jquery, html, css, addclass

I have a litte problem with my form. I want to let users download a Presskit.zip file.

But before they can download it, they have to type the word 'presskit' inside a input text.

If the word 'presskit' is correct, then I want to add a class to the download button.

But it doesnt seems to work. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

[Here's a example:](https://jsfiddle.net/qgot29gc/)

I hope someone can help me :)

Thank you.

HTML

```
<a href="test.zip" class="btn" download="download">Download Presskit</button>
```

CSS

```
.btn {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    padding: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #fff;

    pointer-events: none;

    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.btn.active {
    -webkit-user-select: all;
    -moz-user-select: all;
    -ms-user-select: all;
    user-select: all;
    background-color: #34495e;

    pointer-events: all;
}
input {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 22px;
}
```

Comment: jsfiddle link broken

Comment: Correct your fiddle link

Comment: Please post the code in the question too, just like the error message said when you first tried to post the jsfiddle link.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have fixed it, here's also the link:
https://jsfiddle.net/qgot29gc/

Comment: @Carloscody now try to this code http://jsfiddle.net/rohitmalikazad/qgot29gc/2/

Comment: You need to add jquery to the fiddle as a resource. Here is a forked version from the answer below: https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/qgot29gc/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi now try to this way i m creating a demo .

```js
$('input').on('keyup',function() {
    if($(this).val()=='PRESSKIT'){
      $('.btn').addClass('active');
    }else{
       $('.btn').removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

```css
.btn {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    padding: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #fff;

    pointer-events: none;
    
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.btn.active {
    -webkit-user-select: all;
    -moz-user-select: all;
    -ms-user-select: all;
    user-select: all;
    background-color: #34495e;
    
    pointer-events: all;
}
input {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 22px;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
    <input type="text" class="field-txt" placeholder="Type “PRESSKIT” to start the download.." />
</form>

<a href="test.zip" class="btn" download="download">Download Presskit</button>
```

if you want to be **both** **uppercase** and **lowercase** `presskit` or `PRESSKIT` than used to this  Script

```
$('input').on('keyup',function() {
    if(($(this).val()=='PRESSKIT') || $(this).val()=='presskit'){
      $('.btn').addClass('active');
    }else{
       $('.btn').removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

Comment: than used to this ($(this).val()=='PRESSKIT') || ($(this).val()=='presskit') || ($(this).val()=='Presskit'))

Comment: I would store it in a variable and then use toLowerCase();

Comment: @lharby Than used to this way  store a value in a variable and than compare to you presskit   http://jsfiddle.net/rohitmalikazad/cogv2pcL/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this
$('input').keyup(function() {
if($(this).val()=="presskit"){
    $('.btn').toggleClass('active');}
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But it doensn't seems to work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

you can compare the text and then allow to user to download the link. please have a look of below code.

```
$('input').on('blur, keyup', function() {
if($(this).val()=='PRESSKIT' && $(this).val()!='')
$('.btn').toggleClass('active');
else
 $('.btn').removeClass('active');  
});
```